# Why is my count value greater than the number of elements in an array, when counting duplicate elements in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

When counting the number of duplicate elements in an array, I tested the count value. Somehow the value is bigger than an actual number of elements in an array. My guess is that, in double for loop I'm getting a "double" count. I tried to pin-point the problem, and it's in the count.

I've tried printing the values of my other segments in my code, followed the code and I just can't seem to find why the code i wrote wouldn't work.

```
int main(){

  int a[100];
  int b[100];
  int n,count;

  cin >> n;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin >> a[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    b[i] = a[i];
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
      if(a[i] == b[j]){
        count++;
      //  cout << count << endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

For my test i used: 3, 1 1 2
I expected 1, instead I got 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Because `count` is never initialized, so `count++` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: I tried int count = 0; Now it does work.

Comment: You are comparing each array element with "itself" in the copied array - that means that every single element will enter the `if` at least once

Comment: I still don't understand why doesn't it work without that 0, after if the element is the same, wouldn't it just add +1 to the count.

Comment: @ekaeo What would you be adding 1 to? What is "one plus <some value I don't know>"?

Comment: Now imagine if there are 1000 numbers.  You would be making a million comparisons.  Hopefully you will learn about hash sets, because in the real world, this solution would be considered unacceptable.

Comment: Yes, just thought it's 0 by default, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have:

`a[0]` set to `1`.
`a[1]` set to `1`.
`a[2]` set to `2`.

and

`b[0]` set to `1`.
`b[1]` set to `1`.
`b[2]` set to `2`.

Your comparisons are:

`a[0] == b[0]`  evaluates to `true`.
`a[0] == b[1]`  evaluates to `true`.
`a[0] == b[2]`  evaluates to `false`.

`a[1] == b[0]`  evaluates to `true`.
`a[1] == b[1]`  evaluates to `true`.
`a[1] == b[2]`  evaluates to `false`.

`a[2] == b[0]`  evaluates to `false`.
`a[2] == b[1]`  evaluates to `false`.
`a[2] == b[2]`  evaluates to `true`.

As you can see, there are 5 `true` values in there. That explains why you get the output of

`1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: Indeed. OP seems to be imagining some completely different algorithm. Obvs didn't step through it on paper :(

Comment: I understand that, thank you for your time, but why is it that I get 2, as i expected when I initialize the int count = 0;

Comment: @ekaeo, then there is a disconnect between your post and your tests (which include your code and the input data)

Comment: Yes, the mistake i was looking for was the lack of initialization on my part.